# Why don't we use this board instead?

Tags: feature-request, pgn-viewer

The pgn viewer that is currently being used in this site lack some of the features that the pgn viewer of chess.com has. So why don't we simply use it instead of using our current pgn viewer?

[image: A view of the proposed pgn viewer]

It supports inline comments and annotations. It just requires us to arrange the board and and moves in the Game Editor of chess.com and copy the embed code and paste it here. But I think that the HTML tag for that is currently not supported here. If we could just enable the support for that, we could get a nice pgn viewer for our site.

Comment: The PGN viewer itself that's been implemented on the site *does* allow for PGN comments, but unfortunately that option isn't active in its implementation at chess.SE. If you'd like to voice support for getting that feature activated, there is a meta post here: http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/q/249/167

Comment: *It just requires us to arrange the board and and moves in the Game Editor of chess.com and copy the embed code and paste it here.* Aside from the other points that have been raised, this on its own would be a deal-breaker, assuming I'm understanding correctly. Requiring users to leave the site just to set up a diagram is a Bad Thing in UX.

Answer (score 4):

The question is, *"Is the chess.com's PNG viewer open source?"* - Answer, [*"No"*](http://www.chess.com/legal#termsofservice).

> **Proprietary Rights**
>
> ... provided that you do not (and do not allow any third party to) copy, modify, create a derivative work from, reverse engineer, reverse assemble or otherwise attempt to discover any source code, sell, assign, sublicense, grant a security interest in or otherwise transfer any right in the Software. ...

Even if it's an open source tool, the StackExchange probably didn't interest in using them. SE will try to improve its own code.